# NodeJS - requests made by request library returns [Error: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:]

Tags: node.js, client

I have an ExpressJS tutorial server up and running:

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();

app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Got a GET request for the homepage" );
    res.send( 'Hello GET!' );
} );

app.post( '/', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Retrieved a post request" );
    res.send( 'Hello POST' );
} );

app.delete( '/del_user', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Got a DELETE request for /del_user" );
    res.send( 'Hello DELETE' );
} );

app.get( '/list_user', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Got a GET request for /list_user" );
    res.send( 'Page Listing' );
} );

app.get( '/ab*cd', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Got a GET request for /ab*cd" );
    res.send( 'Page pattern match' );
} );

var server = app.listen( 8081, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
     console.log( "Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port );
} );
```

I want to test the app.post function by building a one time NodeJS client using request library to send a POST request to the server - using this code from another NodeJS related question question:

```
var request = require('request');

var myJSONObject = {};

request( {
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/",
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        body: myJSONObject
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if ( error ) {
            console.log( error );
            return;
        }
        console.log(response);
    } 
);
```

After running the client part I receive this error in the error variable:

**[Error: Invalid protocol: 127.0.0.1:]**

**EDIT**

I just ran this on my home computer and it works without a problem. Maybe some settings at work are at fault here.

Thanks for the help.

I.

Comment: Version of node and express would help. So far.. did you already try: `app.listen( 8081, 127.0.0.1 ,function()`

Answer (score 1):

follow the code on the npm request package site docs ...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

example:

```
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
   console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `json: true` and `body: someObject`, try `json: someObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed `http.request` from NodeJS library with Request package available in NPM. You `require`d the latter, but tried to use syntax of the former.
Simply change first line of client

```
var request = require('request');
```

for

```
var request = require('http').request;
```

And it should go well.

EDIT: You would also have to switch last line into

```
).end();
```